# Missing number -n to n

Tags: c#

There is a number N (i.e., N = 3).

I create an array from -N to N (i.e. {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3})

I randomly remove a number from the array (i.e. {-3, -2, 0, 1, 2, 3}, removed -1)

I shuffle the Array (i.e. {-2, 0, 2, 3, -3, 1})

Write a function

```
public int FindMissing(int[] arr)
```

That takes the shuffled Array from the initial steps and identifies and returns the array's missing number.

I've done it like this, but I think I did it wrong:

```
public partial class findMissingNumber
{
    public static int FindMissing(int[] arr, int N)
    {
        int summ = (N - 1) * N / 2;
        int sumarr = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            sumarr += arr[i];
        }
        return summ - sumarr;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FindMissing(new int[] { -2, 0, 2, 3, -3, 1 }, 3));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Test the code a lot of times and see if you get expected results.  You may want to write a test bench and test code 2000 times and if it always works then it is correct.

Comment: @jdweng I've ran it multiple times but I want to see if there is a way to write it without having the int N in the public static int findmissing(int arr[ ], int N)

Comment: You can get N from the array arr.  int N = arr.Length;

Comment: @jdweng Ah I see that does make sense, I'll try that out and see how that goes. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The sum of all the numbers in an array `[-N, N]` is 0.
If an element is missing it'll be 0 minus the missing number.
If 1 is missing, sum = 0 - 1, therefore the missing number is -sum. Except when 0 is missing.

With LINQ is very easy:

```
using System.Linq;

class findMissingNumber
{
    public static int FindMissing(int[] arr)
    {
        return (arr.Contains(0)) ? -arr.Sum() : 0;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FindMissing(new int[] { -2, 2, 1, 3, -3, -1 }));
    }
}
```

Of course if you know that the array will always miss a number you don't even need to check if 0 is missing and it all boils down to `-arr.Sum()`

Without LINQ is a little longer, but works in the same way:

```
public static int FindMissing(int[] arr)
{
    int sum = 0;
    
    if (Array.FindIndex(arr, x => x == 0) < 0)
        return 0;
    
    Array.ForEach(arr, x => sum += x);
    
    return -sum;
}
```

Again, if you know that an element will alwas be missing, you can avoid looking for zero

---

I used lambdas, but you can write your predicate as you like https://zetcode.com/csharp/predicate/

Comment: I see, that does make sense but I was also wondering is it possible to the same code but just remove the int N from the public static int FindMissing(int[] arr, int N) so basically it would be using this instead public static int FindMissing(int[] arr) 

or is that not possible? Also is it possible to do it by using these instead?
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: Yes, of course, I just forgot to remove it ;)

Comment: thank you for the explanation and example, is there a way I could contact you and let you know if it worked?

Comment: I tried it with the Lambdas but it gave me this error: Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

But I'm unsure why I got that error because I followed your example

Comment: @specterkun I think that the compiler is telling exactly where the problem is :)

Comment: I don't mean to sound obvious, but have you forgotten to the `Main()` method in your class?

Comment: @JackLilhammers : The question the OP ask was poorly written.  The OP really wanted to know if the parameter N was properly used.  Not that the code was written correctly.  The OP didn't need to pass the variable N to the method because he could get the lenth of the array using arr.Length.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes of course he didn't need it